# Reverse Engineering game. What sample size do I need?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, games

I am playing a game where I randomly get 1 of 6 different prizes whenever I do a certain action.  The 6 prizes do not drop at the same rate. Some are more rare than others. I am trying to figure out the percent chance that each prize is given. I have been keeping track of all my attempts for a few weeks, so I have a fairly good idea, but I would like to know how to calculate my confidence level.

For example, lets say that I have received 100 prizes and 8 of them have been a certain kind.  I would say that I have an 8% chance to get that prize on each future attempt. What I want to know is how to calculate the error range or confidence level of that 8%. Is that really 5%-11%?  How many samples do I need to get the error down to under 1%?

I never took a statistics class, so Im new to this kind of math. Thanks!

Comment: May be helpful for the individual proportions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you want is
$$\delta p = \sqrt\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$$
which comes from the variance of a Bernoulli distribution.
So if your observed fraction is $p = 0.08$ with $n=100$ observations, the error bar on $p$ is $\delta p = \sqrt((0.08)(1 - 0.08)/100) = 0.03$, so you would report $p = (8 \pm 3)\%$. That's a 1-$\sigma$ error bar; you can scale it up if you require a higher confidence level.

To find the $n$ you'll need to obtain a given $\delta p$, just use algebra to solve for $n$. If by 1% error you mean $\delta p = 0.01$, you get $n \approx 730$. If by 1% error you mean $\delta p / p  = 0.01$, you get $n \approx 110000$.